# Need windows script to run simple for loop across all the parameters listed in a text file

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to run windows "net view" command against each of these values in test.txt file.

test.txt contains a list of servers as below:

```
\\LB042073 
\\LB042425 
\\LB042507 
\\LB045196
```

I need to run "net view" command against each of these servers.

Below command does not work:

```
Get-Content test.txt | %{& net view}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell:

```
Get-Content test.txt | %{net view $_}
```

`Get-Content` - read the file outputting each line individually

`|` - Pipeline character. It works the same in windows and *nix. It passes the output of one command to the input of the next command

`%` - Alias for `ForEach-Object`. This is a loop construct that will do some code for each object in a list

`{` - Beginning of the code block

`net view $_` - runs the `net.exe` program passing it two parameters view and the contents of the special `$_` variable. The `$_` variable in a `ForEach-Object` loop holds the input item for the current iteration of the loop.

`}` - End of the code block

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit?

Comment: This helps but I need to run a command against each of these values.

test.txt contains a list of servers as below:

    \\LB042073
    \\LB042425
    \\LB042507
    \\LB045196

I need to run "net view" command against each of these servers.

Comment: Above command list only the servers multiple times and does not really run "net view" against each line.


PS C:\Users\a549145> Get-Content test.txt | %{& net view}
Server Name            Remark
---------------------------------------------------------------
\\FSIFAXA930892
\\LA909831

The command completed successfully.

Server Name            Remark
----------------------------------------------------------------
\\..
\\..
command completed successfully.

Server Name            Remark
----------------------------------------------------------------
\\..
\\..
command completed successfully.

Comment: Aaaah...now that you completely changed the question that you were asking, I will change my answer.